# Find if arrangement is possible or not

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

The company has k buses and has a contract with a school which has n students. The school planned to take the students to d different places for d days (each day in one place). Each day the company provides all the buses for the trip. Coordinator has to arrange the students in the buses. He wants to arrange the students in a way that no two students become close friends. In his ridiculous idea, two students will become close friends if and only if they are in the same buses for all d days.

Assume that each bus has an unlimited capacity.

Now we need to find if their is any valid arrangement or if no valid arrangement just print -1.But if their exists any such arrangement we need to tell any one of them.

Example : n=3 and k=2 and d=2 then possible arrangment is :

```
1 1 2 
1 2 1
```

The j-th integer of the i-th line shows which bus the j-th student has to take on the i-th day. We can assume that the buses are numbered from 1 to k.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the values for k, n, and d?For instance is k < d < n? Or are you looking for what restrictions on the values of k, n, and d will make the task possible/impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution if and only if $n \leq k^d$. This is because there are $k^d$ possible different assignments of a student to the $k$ buses over $d$ days.  Two students become close friends if and only if have the same assignment out of the $k^d$ possibilities. If $n \leq k^d$ then you can come up with $n$ different assignments so no two students become close friends. Otherwise by the pigeonhole principle, at least two students must have the same assignment so they become close friends. To generate a solution when one is possible, just represent the assignments as base-$k$ numbers with $d$ digits, and print out all $n$ numbers (i.e. assignments) between $0$ and $n-1$. If the digit is $m$ then the student is assigned to the $(m+1)$th bus on that day.